# Cannot properly decode string

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a string from reading a .txt file that looks something like this:

```
str='\x00I\x00S\x00T\x00A\x00\r\x00\n\x00[\x00/\x00B\x00O\x00D\x00Y\x00]\x00\r\x00\n\x00'
```

The contents of the file is in Portuguese and it won't allow me to encode into utf-8.

When I do `print(str)`, it comes out properly, but when I try and do stuff with the characters, I get the following error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte...`. What do I need to do to get the contents of the string so I can work with it? Thank you.

**Edit:** actually, the print statement is NOT working correctly, as certain accents are replaced with `?` in the print statement.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a unicode string with a leading `u`?  Is this Python 2 or 3?  What are you doing with the characters?  Just trying to access individual ones?

Comment: This looks like it is a Unicode string.  Have you tried converting it from Unicode to UTF-8?

Comment: @cdhowie: It's not Unicode, since it's bytes. It's UTF-16BE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [decode it to a `unicode`](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) first.

```
>>> '\x00I\x00S\x00T\x00A\x00\r\x00\n\x00[\x00/\x00B\x00O\x00D\x00Y\x00]\x00\r\x00\n'.decode('utf-16be')
u'ISTA\r\n[/BODY]\r\n'
```

If it's from a file then use [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) instead of `open()`, passing the appropriate encoding.

Comment: That gives me kanji. Is there a way for me to find out what encoding the string is in?

Comment: No. You can only try various encodings to see if the decoded byte sequence falls within the intended alphabet.

Comment: @David If it's Portuguese I'd try latin9 (ISO-8859-15).